# How do I sleep or skip nights?

Tags: terraria

I was able to build a bed in Terraria and I thought it could allow me to sleep. By clicking on it, instead, I set only the spawn point.

Is it possible sleep in other ways or eventually skip nights (or days)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 1.3 version of Terraria has now a solution for you.

This item is the [Enchanted Sundial](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Enchanted_Sundial).
It is a furniture that can skip one day/night cycle, by setting the time at 4:30 AM. It will also create a new [Angler](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Angler) quest.
It reloads every week of in-game time, and no legit action can hasten the cooldown of the furniture :

-placing multiple sundials ?
-remove and place the sundial again ?
Nope, the sundial's state is stored in the world's data, you'll have to wait a full week of in game time, which is 168 minutes (= 2h48m) before the item gets usable again.

It can be found inside [Wooden](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wooden_Crate), [Iron](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Iron_Crate) or [Golden crates](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golden_Crate), opened in a hardmode world, with better odds of getting it respectively.

Comment: It should be noted that the enchanted sundial is only available in Hardmode.

Comment: It should also be noted that a "week" is 1 in-game week. 1 real-life second is 1 in-game minute, meaning a week is equivalent to 60 seconds per hour * 24 hours per day * 7 days per week = 10,080 seconds = 168 minutes = 2.8 hours (2 hours, 48 minutes).

Answer (score 16):

This is not currently possible in the 1.01 version of Terraria, beds are strictly for setting of your spawn point.

UPDATE: I think this is currently a bug, but in 1.0.3 (And maybe before) if you play in windowed mode, minimize the game by clicking on its icon on the task bar (NOT using the minimize button on the window itself) the game runs VERY fast. You can still hear the background music and wait for it to play the day music... Takes about 15 seconds or so. Also note that the days will go by fast when you do this AND you need to be somewhere 100% safe as, well the game is still running and things will still try to get you.

I think the game is using a fixed time step because of its fixed framerate, but for some reason the framerate jumps up beyond the normal 60 max when minimized in this fashion and so runs very fast.

Answer (score 6):

If you are running the [server console](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Server_Console) (TerrariaServer.exe, should be in the folder you installed to) yourself, you can enter into the console the commands "**dusk**", "**midnight**", "**dawn**", or "**noon**" to change the time of day to that time. Even when playing single player, I tend to run the server console and connect to it, just to have options like this available.

Answer (score 4):

Since 1.4, sleeping in a Bed will make time pass **5 times faster** until you wake up.

*In multiplayer, this requires all online players to be asleep.*

Additionally, if you are in [Journey Mode](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Journey_Mode), you can increase the timescale up to **24 times faster**.

Comment: Is this a joke?

Comment: No? Why should it?

Answer (score 2):

You can skip nights actually, but it's an admin tool..
With it you can drag the sun or moon (if you like) across the horizon.

Comment: Is this admin tool released and available to download?

Comment: @Drake: Drag the sun/moon on the main menu to see what he is talking about, there is a single bit in the Terraria executable that allows you to use the same effect in game. My bet is that the admin tools modify this bit, but I don't know where to find those and can't help you further than positive reverse engineering...

Answer (score 2):

If you're running a server using the dedicated server program that was added into the game package with version 1.04 IIRC, then you have some commands you can use to set the time.

Go to the console when the world is running and try typing:

- `dawn`
- `noon`
- `dusk`
- `midnight`

Answer (score 1):

You can kinda skip time, albeit in a weird way. If you're playing in windowed mode click on the terraria icon on your taskbar (this should minimise it but you will still be able to hear music/sounds) then keep clicking on the taskbar icon of an internet browser and you will hear you action noises from Terraria. It's not a massive time skip but it fast forwards a little

Comment: I am not sure I understood well the part related to internet browser, can you add more details? Can you also estimate the time speed increment (e.g. 1.2x)? Thank you.

Comment: @Drake What JJ1 meant was that like when your using youtube, and you wanted to pause by click the video screen, you'll hear some noises like *Pffft*