# Can you still change night and day in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I thought you could change night/day by dragging moon or sun, but I can't seem to do that anymore?

Comment: Are you on the main menu? That's the only place it's ever worked (to the best of my knowledge)

Comment: @RavenDreamer At some point I recall reading about a bit you could flip in the exe that would allow you to drag the sun/moon across the screen in the game as well as the menu.

Comment: I thought I remembered doing it in game. Oh well, thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sleep or skip nights?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22641/how-do-i-sleep-or-skip-nights)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know you can only change the time of day if you are the host of a server.

There's another related question you could have a look at: [How do I sleep or skip nights?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22641/how-do-i-sleep-or-skip-nights).